# Active stages pointing to this deployment must be moved or deleted

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, stage

i have an api gateway deployment that requires connection to console to create a new deployment. I try to force the deployment automatically so I add `stage_description = "Deployed at: ${timestamp()}"` in the  `aws_api_gateway_deployment` resource.

When i test the first time is passed but in the next `terraform apply` I get the error: `Active stages pointing to this deployment must be moved or deleted`

```
-- Deployment ------------------------------------
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "dev_api_front_deployment" {
depends_on = [
aws_api_gateway_method.dev_api_front_auth_register_post,
aws_api_gateway_integration.dev_api_front_auth_register_post-integration,
aws_api_gateway_method.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_post,
aws_api_gateway_integration.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_post-integration,
aws_api_gateway_method.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_resend_post,
aws_api_gateway_integration.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_resend_post-integration

]
rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dev_api_front.id
stage_name = var.environment
stage_description = "Deployed at: ${timestamp()}"

}
```

I try to change my code like this but i still get the error :( i use Terraform v0.12.31 with the provider 3.70.0

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "dev_api_front_deployment" {

triggers = {
redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
aws_api_gateway_method.dev_api_front_auth_register_post,
aws_api_gateway_integration.dev_api_front_auth_register_post-integration,
aws_api_gateway_method.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_post,
aws_api_gateway_integration.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_post-integration,
aws_api_gateway_method.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_resend_post,
aws_api_gateway_integration.dev_api_front_auth_register_confirm_resend_post-integration

]))
}
rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dev_api_front.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "dev_api_front_stage" {
deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.dev_api_front_deployment.id
rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dev_api_front.id
stage_name = var.environment
}
```